# RotatingGeomeryUpdater is not abstract and does not overide abstract method updateData(Geomerty)?

Tags: java

I have created a class with the name of **RotatingGeometryUpdater** and when I compile it I find the error:
 **RotatingGeometryUpdater is not abstract a
nd does not override abstract method updateData(Geometry) in GeometryUpdater
public class RotatingGeometryUpdater implements GeometryUpdater**

what shoud I do?

My code is.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.media.j3d.*;
import javax.vecmath.*;


public class RotatingGeometryUpdater implements GeometryUpdater
{
 long lastFrame = 0;

 public RotatingGeometryUpdater ( )
 {
 }
 // public abstract void updateData(Geometry g){}
public boolean update( Graphics graphics, RenderingEngine engine,
 GeometryArray geometry, int index, long frameNumber )
 {
  if ( lastFrame != frameNumber )
  {
    lastFrame = frameNumber;
Vector3d viewAngle = engine.getViewAngle( );
 viewAngle.x += 1;
       engine.setViewAngle( viewAngle );
  }
   return false;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
what shoud I do?
```

You should implement the method that the error message is telling you is missing. When you implement an interface, you agree to the contract that is specified by the interface. This concept is called [design by contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract).

As your class is a concrete class, it must provide an implementation for *updateData(Geometry)*.

This is because someone might use your class like this:

```
GeometryUpdater geom = new  RotatingGeometryUpdater();
geom.updateData();
^-- this line would break, as you have not implemented the method!
```

So how do you implent this?

```
public void updateData(Geometry g){
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: ok thanks . it compiles but now throws the Exception like this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/media/j3d/GeometryUpdater

Comment: Your classpath is wrong so java cant find the class. As a simple fix, put your class in the same package as where the class creating the object is

Comment: It is impossible to tell without seeing how your project is set up. Compile-time, the class is found. But run-time, it is not. I still say it's a classpath problem.